# textViewDidChange Calling two times while Chinese keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, ios9, nslocalizedstring

- `shouldChangeTextInRange` method working fine while English text but not working when Chinese keyword entered and because of that I use the `textDidChange` method to get the Chinese text but when Chinese text enter then `textDidChange` calling two times, so I get each string two times.
- What should I do to get the Chinese text? I know that I can easily get the Chinese text using `textview.text` but I use the html string in textview, so if I get string using `textview.text` then I can't get html string. Suggest me some solution so I can get the html string from textview for both English and Chinese text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.pWebView evaluateJavaScript: @"document.body.innerText"
                    completionHandler:^(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                     NSString *aString = result;
             }];
```